# My 2 years old dog doesn't want to eat, she has a serious weight loss

Tags: dogs, health, eating, weight-loss

My 2 years old dog has serious problems recently and I can't figure out what's wrong with her.

Symptoms include:

- Noticeable weight loss;
- Inactive (lays on the ground all day);
- Not eating at all (or eating at night very little), but drinks water;
- Has almost no energy;
- Barks very rarely;
- Doesn't play;
- Nothing makes her happy.

My pet has this symptoms for almost a week. She doesn't like when I touch her on the belly, I think her stomach hurts. Unfortunately, we're in the small town and there isn't any vet here (just one vet with very bad reputation).

Any of your advice will be very important to me.

Comment: All the symptoms you list indicate that this is a medical emergency and you must get her treated **as quickly as possible**. The only advice I can give you is to go to the vet anyways. Maybe she swallowed something that now blocks her intestine or something that causes injury to the intestine, which causes extreme pain. You must get her checked by a vet. Without knowing what exactly is wrong with her, any attempt at treating her at home could do even more damage. Treatment by a bad vet is better than no treatment at all.